# Tooltip in Bootstrap 3 has unwanted CSS effects in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

Please see my live site http://mozzor.com and hover over the circle icons at the top. Notice two effects that occur only in Firefox (I'm using FF23):

1) There is a blue underline added to the text of the tooltip

2) The text renders upon hovering, then after a moment, seems to blur itself.

I'm having trouble debugging this with Firebug...I can't find a css element that corresponds to either of these effects.

Just in case, here is some relevant code for how I style the tooltips:

```
// Variable currentSelect corresponds to hex color value
// selected in the jQuery widget seen at the top left side of the page
$('#notebookIcon,#pencilIcon,#headphoneIcon').tooltip().on("mouseover", function () {
    var tooltip = $(this).next(".tooltip");
    //Box
    tooltip.find(".tooltip-inner").css({
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        color: currentSelect,
        borderColor: currentSelect,
        borderWidth: "1px",
        borderStyle: "solid"
    });
    //Arrow
    tooltip.find(".tooltip-arrow").css({
        //borderTopColor: currentSelect,
        //borderLeftColor: currentSelect,
        //borderRightColor: currentSelect,
        borderBottomColor: currentSelect
    });
});
```

EDIT: Second issue seems to deal with font aliasing slowly in Firefox. Issue still persists after trying several different fonts. For more information, see below:

Github issue: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10218

Bugzilla issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=909814

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is the underline, which is dictated by the CSS [`text-decoration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) property.  I'm not exactly sure why it's happening on Firefox (Chrome seems to have it correct, because text-decoration for your menu items is set to none).  Here's a quick fix, but I'll see if I can find the cause.

```
#iconrow a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

About the second question: I don't understand why you can't do this with CSS.

Comment: I'm trying to stop the effect using CSS (or some other means), but I don't know how to stop it

Comment: Have you changed anything on the page since you posted this?  I'm not seeing the bluing effect anymore.  Now that I think about, it could be a text-shadow.  Try `*{text-shadow: none}` to see if that fixes it for you, and then you can narrow it down if it works.

Comment: Ok your solution for the underlines worked, but I'm still getting the blur effect and `*{text-shadow: none}` did not fix. I'm wondering if it's an issue with either Bootstrap or Firefox...

Comment: I looked pretty hard, and I'm not seeing anything in the style sheets, computed styles, or user-agent style sheets.  I can tell you that I know how to debug CSS very well, so you might want to see if any Firefox developers know.  Try posting a bug on [bugzilla.mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).  If you get an answer, make sure to come back here and click "Answer Your Question".

Comment: I've posted an issue on Bootstrap Github to see if they know anything (see my edit in question)...I don't have a bugzilla account, but if you file the bug and post link to it here, I'll gladly mark yours as answer (since you already got half of it fixed).

Comment: Eh, Don't bother...issue already closed on Github as a font aliasing problem. I'll just make note of it in the question and give you credit for the other portion.